# How to refer to css file in codeigniter? 2.0

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

What is the difference if I store the **main.css** file in `/webroot/myapp/css` or `/webroot/assets/css`?

This one is working...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

This one does not...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/myapp/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

Why?

Comment: Where is the file located, assets or myapp directory?

Comment: of course in the first case the file is in the /webroot/assets/css folder (and I van refer it, and it is working)... the secound case is in the /webroot/myapp/css, and I cannot refer it to get working :-(

Comment: the problem was with the .htaccess file
now it's working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the URL helper and then add  to your href like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: may be the question is a little bit confusing... (and silly)...
so... the CI application and systems folders are in the /webroot/myapp folder... I would like to move them out of the /webroot folder, but it seems the css file must be somewhere in the webroot... how can I refer to the css file if I move the myapp folder out of /webroot?

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case, you need to change your SYSTEM FOLDER NAME inside index.php to the absolute path to the CI install.  Make sense?